# Mystery of the Restarting Docker Container

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, restart

I have noticed a pattern that is easily reproducible but I can not answer why for the life of me its happening.  For some reason if I use the command `docker-compose kill` (to kill all the containers), and then start it back up again with `docker-compose -d` my web container gets stuck into an infinite loop of restarting.  I have looked all over the internet for answers on this and could not find anything.

Looks something like below which shows the steps to see what is happening.

[image]

Please refer to this post I made ([Docker-Compose won't volume my php.ini file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41691584/docker-compose-wont-volume-my-php-ini-file)) for my complete docker setup that is used here in the exact same way, but I'll attach my docker-compose file here for quick reference.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
    dblive:
        image: mysql:5.5.52
        volumes:
            - ./db_data_live:/var/lib/mysql
        restart: always
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ****
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ****
            MYSQL_USER: ****
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ****

    dbdev:
        image: mysql:5.5.52
        volumes:
            - ./db_data_dev:/var/lib/mysql
        restart: always
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:****
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ****
            MYSQL_USER: ****
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ****

    phpmyadmin:
        depends_on:
            - dblive
            - dbdev
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        environment:
            PMA_ARBITRARY : 1
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "8081:80"

    web:
        build: ./
        depends_on:
            - dblive
            - dbdev
        volumes:
            - ./web:/var/www
            - ./config/custom.php.ini:/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/custom.php.ini
            - ./logs/apache_error.log:/var/log/apache2/error.log
            - ./logs/apache_access.log:/var/log/apache2/access.log
            - ./config/apache_default.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
        restart: always
        ports: 
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
```

**Steps to Reproduce**

1. Refer to my linked post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41691584/docker-compose-wont-volume-my-php-ini-file) to get my complete setup to follow along.
2. Run **docker-compose up -d**.  This will start the containers.
3. Run **docker ps** to verify they are all up and have been for 15 seconds
   or more.
4. Run **docker-compose kill** to stop the containers.
   Run `docker-compose up -d` to start the containers again, and **follow up with a docker ps every 5 seconds to notice the consistent restarting on the web container.** Feel free to kill and restart many times and the restarting will keep happening.
5. Interestingly enough, comment out a line in the docker-compose.yml
   file.  In my case I commented out the voluming of the php.ini file
   like this, `#-
   ./config/custom.php.ini:/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/custom.php.ini`
6. Run **docker-compose kill** to stop the containers again.  Then run **docker-compose up -d** and **this time the container will magically work without restarting??**

**My question is why does changing the docker-compose.yml file slightly and then starting up cause it to work now?** *If I kill the container for any reason after this and try to start up again **without making a change in the docker-compose.yml** file then the restart loop occurs on the web container.*  **Why is it doing this?**

Attached below is an image showing it working after the previous restarts from the first image I attached.  In the image please ignore and excuse the `ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError:` I forgot I had XX'ed out my MySQL passwords so make sure you just put something there to make it happy.  The content after the error shows that it suddenly starts working again.

[image]

Comment: What does `docker logs` and `docker inspect` show for the restarting container?

Comment: Can you give me an example how to use those commands? At what point would you like me to use the commands also? (For example when its restarting, after its restarting etc...)

Comment: I also want to note that just recently I discovered if I do docker-compose down I don't seem to have the restart issue that occurs with docker-compose kill.  Maybe I just should not be using kill??

Comment: The commands take the container name as an argument (if you run without, it will print a usage). Output when the container is currently down and waiting for it's timeout to restart is fine.

Comment: Do you have any Dockerfile involved for web? I know every step in a Dockerfile is a layer itself and is cached. So maybe docker-compose.yml instructions are also cached (I don't know) and as soon as you touch something that layer recreates and the following layers also do. Not sure if I can satisfy your questions, but just to try thing you may run "docker-compose up --force-recreate"

Comment: Yes the Dockerfile is the other question, please refer to the link, I just didn't have enough space to add everything in the question.  Regarding BMitch I will run the command now to see what it shows.

Comment: I just got what you were saying mayid, you might be right about the cache of results since dockerfiles do that, I will try your command also.  I recently discovered that docker-compose down seems to work also, maybe that gracefully brings them down removing cache?

Comment: You were correct Mayid that was the error, basically I need to use docker-compose down instead to get rid of the cached older copies.  This was causing the weird random restarts.  You can post that as answer.

Comment: I think it's because you set restart policy to `always`. When container got killed, docker attempt to bring it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is to not use run docker-compose kill but use **docker-compose down** instead because docker-compose kill only kills the containers but does not clear the cache that docker-compose makes for you.

Comment: Thank you sir!, spent a lot of time, even tried using different versions of mysql/mariadb and it just kept restarting...then I tried using docker run separately and it worked properly, but docker-compose was not working at all...in case someone else is going through the same, this worked!