# Cannot edit php.ini file in Docker

Tags: php, docker

I'm trying to edit the php.ini inside Docker, so I need to do `docker-compose up`. But every time I do `docker-compose up`, php.ini returns as it was before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to mount the php.ini from the host, as docker-compose up will terminate the container and will launch a new container which does not container the modified php.ini.

```
volumes:
   - ./config/custom.php.ini:/etc/php(version)/apache2/conf.d/custom.php.ini
```

> By default the scan directory for extra php files will look in the
>   conf.d directory. These files will overwrite the settings of the main
>   php.ini. I tested this with the asp_tag option turning it Off and On.
>   It works fine as long as you do the following below.
>
> The trick to making this work is to use `docker-compose down` instead of
>   `docker-compose kill`

you can check further [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-get-access-to-php-ini-file/68986/5) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41691584/docker-compose-wont-volume-my-php-ini-file)