# No test feedback is displayed when running phpunit

Tags: php, laravel, docker, phpunit, tdd

When trying this command `docker-compose exec app php ./vendor/bin/phpunit`

Or inside container like `/vendor/bin/phpunit`

Results are like:

```
PHPUnit 8.5.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

 ..F..FFFEE
```

While I'd need **more details** like time of test and failures info.
I'm able to get some info by enabling `stopOnFailure = true`

But it's not ideal because it stops on the first one but I would need all of test to run and see the result.

I would need something like:

```
PHPUnit 8.5.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

.......................E.......................................  63 / 116 ( 54%)
.....................................................           116 / 116 (100%)

Time: 1.2 minutes, Memory: 48.50 MB

There was 1 error:
ERRORS!
Tests: 116, Assertions: 219, Errors: 1.
```

Comment: I'm not sure PHPUnit supports displaying the time of test out the box. 

See the available options here: https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.0/textui.html

If necessary you could also create your own formatter: http://php5.laurent-laville.org/compatinfo/blog/201505-PHPUnit-ResultPrinter.html

Comment: @MattInamdar Ofcourse it does, I have no problem when running tests out of Docker container. every things work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a docker, the php.ini configurations to display errors are disabled by default.

**Solution 1:**

Update the PHP configuration for you docker with:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
```

By referring to https://stackoverflow.com/a/40120445/494907

**Solution 2:**

Link a `bootstrap` file in `phpunit.xml` as

```
<phpunit bootstrap="init.php">
```

Create init.php in the directory of phpunit.xml:

```
<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
```

Comment: I tried solution 1 but unfortunately it did not work

Comment: To confirm please check the values using phpinfo()?

Comment: Values have not changed. the odd thing is that it work on machine with fresh Laravel, but not on other machine with Laravel 6 !

Comment: I have followed https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-laravel-nginx-and-mysql-with-docker-compose
I really need help. I'd appreciate any help

Comment: I followed the tutorial, installed it on mac and I am able to run the tests with the errors directly. Please share the phpunit.xml so that Ii can compare it with mine.

Comment: this will likely not solve the problem at hand but as an alternative to the answer, phpunit php ini values can be configured in the phpunit.xml configuration file: [Setting PHP INI settings, Constants and Global Variables - 3. The XML Configuration File - PHPUnit](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.3/configuration.html#setting-php-ini-settings-constants-and-global-variables)